# Connection Timeout for Spring Redis using Redis Cloud

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, redis

I am trying to connect Redis in my Spring application.
I have created a Redis Database in [Redis Cloud](https://redis.com/try-free/)`redis-10228.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:10228`.

I have configured the following in my `application.properties`

```
spring.redis.host=redis-10228.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:10228

spring.redis.password=<password-from-redis-cloud>
```

I am still getting Redis Connection failure event after providing password.

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis-10228.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:10228
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis-10228.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:10228
```

Any misconfiguration done from my part?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the redis port in a different property:

```
spring.redis.host=redis-10228.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com
spring.redis.port=10228
```

See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.5.3/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html#boot-redis-configuration) for more details.

Comment: Getting same error.

Comment: I successfully connected to it. I gave authorization required. Test with "docker run --rm --name redis-cli -it goodsmileduck/redis-cli redis-cli -h redis-10228.c15.us-east-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com -p 10228 ping" to see if it is a network problem from your side